# Ionic Splash Timeout Not Working After First Time

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my IONIC app I am hoping to after filling in a form show a screen for a time of 3 seconds.

I've managed to get the app to do this however it only works once then the next time the form is filled in the screen sticks?

**See my controller:**

```
.controller('splashScrn', function($location, $timeout) {

    $timeout(function() {
        $location.path('/welcome');
    }, 3000);

})
```

My Welcome Controller for the form which loads the splash after form complete.

```
.controller('welcomeCtrl', function($scope, $http, $state, Post, Idle, $window) {

        $scope.newPost = function() {
            var post = new Post($scope.postData);
            post.$save();

            $state.go('splashscreen');
        }

})
```

Comment: Maybe it's something related to [cache](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/)?

Comment: Is there a way to stop the app from cache that page? @DavidePastore

Comment: Yes, by adding `cache: false` for related state.